# How to retrieve image from database using ComboBox in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

i'm having a problem about the event of my `ComboBox` when i try to retrieve image by it. Because when i use this one:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim connstring As String = "server = localhost; user id = root; database = db; password = root"
        Dim Sql As String = "SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE cid= '" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "'"
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Sql, conn)
        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
        conn.Open()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        dr.Read()
        If IsDBNull(dr("photo")) = False Then
            Dim imagebytes As Byte() = CType(dr("photo"), Byte())
            Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(imagebytes)
                PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
                PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            End Using
        End If
        conn.Close()
End Sub
```

this error occurs : `Operator '&' is not defined for string "SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE ci" and type 'DataRowView'.`

but if i use this one :

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted

    Dim connstring As String = "server = localhost; user id = root; database = db; password = root"
    Dim Sql As String = "SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE cid= '" & ComboBox1.SelectedIndex & "'"
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Sql, conn)
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
    conn.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()
    If IsDBNull(dr("photo")) = False Then
        Dim imagebytes As Byte() = CType(dr("photo"), Byte())
        Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(imagebytes)
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
            PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        End Using
    End If
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

at first selection is working, but when i select another item in my `ComboBox`, the Form hangs(Not Responding). is there anything wrong with my code or laptop?

this is how i populated my `ComboBox`es:

```
Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    HookKeyboard()
    Me.TopMost = True
    con.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;user id=root;database=db;password=root")
    Try
        con.Open()

        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "SELECT case when SCQ='0' or cfname='Select a Candidate' then cfname else CONCAT_WS(' ', idn, cfname, cmname, clname,'from', cparty,'party') end names, " & _
            "cpos, cid from candidate WHERE cpos='President' AND candidacy='Filed' OR " & _
                       "cpos='Vice President' AND candidacy='Filed' OR " & _
                       "cpos='Secretary' OR " & _
                       "cpos='Treasurer' OR " & _
                       "cpos='Auditor' OR " & _
                       "cpos='Public Information Officer' OR " & _
                       "cpos='Peace Officer' OR " & _
                       "cpos='Representative (Grade 7)' order by SCQ desc "
        End With
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        With ComboBox1
            Dim dv = New DataView(dt, "cpos='President'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            .DisplayMember = "names"
            .ValueMember = "names"
            .DataSource = dv
        End With
        With ComboBox2
            Dim dv1 = New DataView(dt, "cpos='Vice President'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            .DisplayMember = "names"
            .ValueMember = "names"
            .DataSource = dv1
        End With
        With ComboBox3
            Dim dv2 = New DataView(dt, "cpos='Secretary'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            .DisplayMember = "names"
            .ValueMember = "names"
            .DataSource = dv2
        End With
        With ComboBox4
            Dim dv3 = New DataView(dt, "cpos='Treasurer'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            .DisplayMember = "names"
            .ValueMember = "names"
            .DataSource = dv3
        End With
        With ComboBox5
            Dim dv4 = New DataView(dt, "cpos='Auditor'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            .DisplayMember = "names"
            .ValueMember = "names"
            .DataSource = dv4
        End With
        With ComboBox6
            Dim dv5 = New DataView(dt, "cpos='Public Information Officer'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            .DisplayMember = "names"
            .ValueMember = "names"
            .DataSource = dv5
        End With
        With ComboBox7
            Dim dv6 = New DataView(dt, "cpos='Peace Officer'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            .DisplayMember = "names"
            .ValueMember = "names"
            .DataSource = dv6
        End With
        With ComboBox8
            Dim dv7 = New DataView(dt, "cpos='Representative (Grade 7)'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            .DisplayMember = "names"
            .ValueMember = "names"
            .DataSource = dv7
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: normally when you use a DataSource, you want to show one thing to the user (Name) but have something else available as the key (cid).  So when setting up the CBOs you should use `cid` as the `ValueMember` and use that for the SQL later: `SQL = "SELECT... WHERE cid = " & cbo.SelectedValue `

Comment: now the error says `Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()` that points here :  `If IsDBNull(dr("photo")) = False Then`

Comment: I dont think that query is ideal for what you want.  If you glue all the info together (CONCAT_WS) you need to parse it to get what you want.  I am not sure 'cid' is even in the `names` string (unless idn is it).  A simpler way would be to create a DataSet with 8 tables in it one for each position then use that as the CBO data source.

Comment: i put it like this `SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE idn=CONCAT_WS(' ', idn, cfname, cmname, clname,'from', cparty,'party')` and it works with no errors but no matter what/who i select still the last one in the list's image is showing. There are 2 items in my combobox.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you would CONCAT fields when you dont care about the pieces or to make something new for the user.  For instance concat FirstName and LastName into a FullName.  Thats not really the case here, you *do* want to get at some of the info.  Your query can be simplified using a procedure to get the data for each position (ie a dataset with 7 or 8 tables - one for each position).

```vb
Public Class FormX

    Private myDS As DataSet          ' our data set for the results

    Private Form_Load(....
         myDS = New DataSet

         FillPositionInfo("President")
         FillPositionInfo("Vice-President")
         ...etc

         ' bind to CBOs:
        With ComboBox1
            .DisplayMember = "FullName"      ' what to show
            .ValueMember = "cid"             ' value to return to code
            .DataSource = myDS.Tables("President")
        End With

' add a table to the DS with the candidate info for the requested position
Private Sub FillPositionInfo(position As String)

    ' maybe CONCAT to create a full name field
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT cid, ... FROM Candidate WHERE cpos = @cpos"

    ' youd use MySql Objects - I only have SQL Server and Access available
    Using con As OleDbConnection = GetConnection()
        con.Open()
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con),
            da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql.Value, con)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpos", position)
            da.SelectCommand = cmd

            ' add a new Tbl named "President" or whatever is requested
            myDS.Tables.Add(position)            
            da.Fill(myDS, position)            ' fill the table
           ' debug - look in the output window
            For n As Integer = 0 To myDS.Tables(position).Rows.Count - 1
                Console.WriteLine(myDS.Tables(position).Rows(n).Item("cname")
            Next
        End Using            ' dispose cmd and da
        con.Close            ' return connection to pool
    End Using                ' dispose con
End Sub
```

Notes:

I am not familiar with all the intricacies and details of your app and database, so there will likely be things to fix and modify.  It is the principles involved which are being illustrated.

Since the text for the positions is now crucial, you'd probably want to use Constants or an array of names to prevent typos.  E.g:

```
Private posTitles As String() = {"President", "Vice President"...}
Private Enum TitleIndex
    President = 0
    VP = 1
    ...
End Enum
...
myDS.Tables.Add(posTitles(TitleIndex.VP))     ' add named tbl using array text
CBO.DataSource = myDS.Tables(TitleIndex.VP)  ' reference by position
```

The point is that you want to be sure to use the same exact text for the DS Tables, CBO, SQL etc and not use "Vice President" here and "Vice-President" elsewhere.

By not gluing everything together, your original question may be obsoleted.  If the SQL for creating the tables is minimal ("SELECT Fname, LName, CID From ...") then you will need to hit the DB again to get more info like the photo:

```
' assumes cid is the PK and mapped as the ValueMember
Sql = "SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE cid = '" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "'"
```

(If `cid` is a numeric, you dont need or want the ticks - that may be a data type conversion).

If you use "SELECT *", then each `DataTable` will already have all the info in them with no need to look anything up.  The byte array for the selected candidate would be something like:

```
myDS.Tables(X).Rows(Cbo.SelectedIndex).Item("photo")`
```

You'd still have to convert it to an actual image, but there is no need to find it.  There are several ways to go about this - so you may want to tinker with it if that is how you go about it.

Finally, note that it is a *much* better practice to use SQL Parameters as shown in `FillPositionInfo`.  Far fewer errors in the string format, data type mismatches and protection from SQL injection attacks.